# How to change the action of a button in child component from a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have 2 components `TermsOfServices` which is used in 2 parent components. One of the parent components is my `ReadTosPage` component. I have a button in my child component which manages a conditional display of icons according to the number of the page on which it is placed. What I would like to do is only change the behavior of the button which have the check icon in my parent `ReadTosPage` component so that it closes the page without sending any information. Just close the page. How can I do this from the parent? Thanks

my `FAB` button in `TermsOfServices` :

```
<Fab position="right-bottom" slot="fixed" color="pink" onClick={() => this.handleNext()}>
   {currentTosId + 1 === termsOfServices.length &&
   <Icon ios="f7:check" aurora="f7:check" md="material:check" />}
   {currentTosId !== termsOfServices.length &&
   <Icon ios="f7:chevron_right" aurora="f7:chevron_right" md="material:chevron_right" />}
</Fab>
```

`ReadTosPage` :

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { intlShape } from 'react-intl';
import {
  Page,
  Navbar,
  Block,
} from 'framework7-react';
import TermsOfServices from '../components/TermsOfServices';

class ReadTosPage extends PureComponent {
  static contextTypes = {
    intl: intlShape,
  };

  render() {
    const { intl } = this.context;
    const { formatMessage } = intl;

    return (
      <Page>
        <Navbar backLink title={formatMessage({ id: 'press_yui_tos_title' })} />
        <Block>
          <TermsOfServices />
        </Block>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}

export default ReadTosPage;
```

Comment: Your example should be reduced to a minimal example to help you get a concise and clear answer. From what I am reading, it sounds like your child component just needs a prop that lets the parent tell the child’s button to either be a callback the parent can use or to change the behavior of the button in the child to close the page (I do not know which component has control over the closing operation)

Comment: Typically you handle child -> parent communication by passing a function to the child, so in this case you'd want to define a function to do what you want in `ReadTosPage`, and then pass it into `TermsOfServices`, so that you can call it there